# assigning unique ID via find() and each() iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

For each `.chart_edit_toolbar` and its children `input` elements I want to append `"-" + index` to the `id` attr before initializing the `buttonset`. The goal here is a unique `id` for each duplicate `buttonset` and `input` radio.

```
$("div.chart_edit_toolbar").each(function(index,event) {
    $(this)
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-" + index) // works as expected
        .find("input")
            .each(function(i,e) {
                $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id", + "-" + index)); // "[object Object]"
            })
        .buttonset();
});
```

In the above code the `id` of the `div` is changed as expected, but the `id` of the `input` fields becomes `[object Object]`.

I'm also open to a more efficient way of accomplishing this if you have one. I will also need to change the `for` attribute of the accompanying `label` element so if you can include that in your solution it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

---

Sample HTML (repeated several times across several jQuery UI tabs):

```
<div id="chart_edit_toolbar" class="alignleft chart_edit_toolbar">

                        <input type="radio" id="arrow_tool" name="tool_radio" checked="checked">
                        <label for="arrow_tool">Arrow</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="text_tool" name="tool_radio" >
                        <label for="text_tool">Text</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="tri_tool" name="tool_radio">
                        <label for="tri_tool">Tri</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="rect_tool" name="tool_radio">
                        <label for="rect_tool">Rect</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="clear_tool" name="tool_radio">
                        <label for="clear_tool">CLEAR</label>

                        <input type="radio" id="undo_tool" name="tool_radio">
                        <label for="undo_tool">UNDO</label>

                    </div>
```

---

If it helps someone else, here is the implemented solution:

```
$("div.chart_edit_toolbar").each(function(i) {
    $(this)
        .attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-" + i)
        .find("input, label")
        .each(function(index,el) {
            if ($(el).is("input"))
                $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-" + i);
            else if ($(el).is("label"))
                $(this).attr("for", $(this).attr("for") + "-" + i);
        });
}).buttonset();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses is in the wrong spot.

this

```
$(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id", + "-" + index)); 
                                    ^
```

should be

```
$(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-" + index);
```

The `attr` setter returns back the jQuery object hence you were getting `[object Object]` when stringified.